# How can one civilization's unit be in another civilization's city?

Tags: civilization-5

Is this just a bug? (This is very late game when nearly every tile in the world is filled up with some civilization's unit.)

[image]

Comment: What kind of unit is it?

Comment: @Kyralessa: As the screenshot above shows, it's an X-Com Squad.